# Vertical alignment of HStack not working and not intuitive

Tags: swiftui

I have this code:

```
HStack (alignment:.center) {
  Text("50")
  ProgressView("", value: 50, total: 100)
  Text("100")
  Text("mg")
}
```

the result is

[image]

I want this

[image]

I have tried everything like adding alignment center to HStack, adding the progress view inside a VStack, etc

Why Apple never manage to make things related to interface design work intuitively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another way like not using "", and it works as you want.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        HStack  {
            Text("50")
            ProgressView(value: 50, total: 100)  // <<: Here
            Text("100")
            Text("mg")
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

---

The Version that you used is also good, but has another usage like this down code. And it needs the **ProgressView** pushed down for Text, actually, in your code **ProgressView** thinks that **""** is the information to show! that is why you see that.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        HStack  {
            Text("50")
            ProgressView("This part is for information to help", value: 50, total: 100)
            Text("100")
            Text("mg")
        }

    }
}
```

[image]